# Engine transporter

Tags: engine, vw, transporter

My VW TDI transporters engine dies after I remove my foot from the accelerator panel. And won’t start again when hot. It is also blowing excessive white smoke.

All started after refuelling.

Answer (score 1):

If this indeed is fuel related It maybe that you have filled up with contaminated fuel. Unfortunately to check this properly you'll need to have the fuel tank drained. If the fuel is found to be contaminated with water etc then you'll obviously require fresh fuel, along with having the lines and injectors/pump etc cleared out.

Comment: And don't forget to clean/replace the filters as well.

Comment: If draining the fuel is what I need to do how do you do that process?

Comment: Unless you do your own vehicle maintenance or have experience you'll need to take the vehicle to a garage, in the vast majority of cases the fuel tank will have to be removed from the vehicle and drained, then properly cleaned/flushed out. You can't really just use a pump and hose to remove contaminated fuel as there is always a little left over when using a pump etc, so the tank needs removing, tipping to one side, draining, then flushing.